# shopify How can I hold a payment for 24 hours?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I need to add $1 trial product, but instead of charging the $1, we just "authorize" it (temp hold of $1 -- looks like a charge to customer on their statement, but not charged yet)

Since many people, in offers like this, cancel right away after getting the first trial/cheap item:

if someone cancels their plan within 24 hours from their trial purchase, we remove the auth, do NOT charge them the dollar, and DO NOT send them anything

if they don't cancel, after 24 hours we finalize the $1 charge, fulfill their trial order.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

In Settings -> Payment providers Shopify has an option about capturing payments:
[image]

You can set it to "Manually capture payment for orders." in Shopify,

And then you should write your own separate integration with the payment system which will charge customers if authorization happened more than 24 hours ago. (Maybe your payment provider can do that automatically. You can ask him)

You can read some information from official documentation: https://help.shopify.com/manual/payments/payment-authorization